# Recoding Likert Scales within dataframe -recommendations for learning R for research methodology?

Tags: r, statistics, survey

Just recently began my journey in R and finally getting the hang of things. I have a very simple question yet I'm unable to find the answer I'm looking for.

I have a dataset of survey responses that were collected using a Likert type scale. Some of the range from very strongly disagree to the opposite (1-7) while others are 1-5. I'm looking for a simple way of recoding each column within the dataset, preferably using the dplyr package as I'm trying to master it. So far, I have this:

df is my dataframe which contains columns Q2.1_1: Q2.5_1. I need the new recoded columns to be numeric as they are currently factors (I want to later run descriptives).

The problem with this line is that it creates a vector that recodes it, but not within my df dataframe. I'm not sure if I should be appending this to df or if there's a better way to just edit within df itself.

```
as.numeric(recode(df$Q2.1_1, "Very slightly or not at all"=1, .... etc))
```

Comment: Did you assign your recoded variable back to the original df, perhaps as a new variable so that you preserve the original factor?  E.g., df$newQ2 <- your code.

Comment: Hah! That was exactly what I needed. I'm used to .append in Python for this.. That just solved my problem I was trying to figure out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like the following:

```
mydata <- data.frame(x = c("A lot", "Some", "Not at all"))

mydata <- mutate(mydata, x_recoded = recode(x, "A lot" = 1, "Some" = 2, "Not at all" = 3))

mydata

           x x_recoded
1      A lot         1
2       Some         2
3 Not at all         3
```

This code is:

1. Creating the sample data
2. Using dplyr's `mutate()` function to create a new variable `x_recoded`
3. Assigning the mutated data frame `mydata` back to itself so it now has `x_recoded` in it

`recode` infers that the variable is numeric since numbers are on the right-hand-side in the recodes, so you don't need to use `as.numeric`.

Comment: Thanks for breaking it down-- exactly what I needed. Now, using your previous example, how do I recode more than 1 variable?

mydata <- mutate(mydata, x_recoded(1:10) = recode(x1:x10, "A lot" = 1, "Some" = 2, "Not at all" = 3))

Comment: dplyr has `mutate` variants `mutate_at()` and `mutate_if()` that allow you to easily apply the same function to multiple variables. If you would rather keep it simple, `mutate` can handle multiple operations in one call, separated by commas (so you'd basically have the same code 10 times with different variable names).